# How to create a figure of subplots of grouped bar charts in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to combine multiple grouped bar charts into one figure, as the image below shows.
[grouped bar charts in a single figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MN9NK.png)

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3']
yesterday_test1_mean = [20, 12, 23]
yesterday_test2_mean = [21, 14, 25]
today_test1_mean = [18, 10, 12]
today_test2_mean = [13, 13, 9]
```

Firstly I created each grouped bar chart by `plt.subplots()`

```
x = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.3

fig1, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x-width/2, yesterday_test1_mean, width)
rects2 = ax.bar(x+width/2, yesterday_test2_mean, width)

fig2, ax = plt.subplots()
rects3 = ax.bar(x-width/2, today_test1_mean, width)
rects4 = ax.bar(x+width/2, today_test2_mean, width)
```

Then, I used `add_subplot` in an attempt to treat `fig1` and `fig2` as new axes in a new figure.

```
fig_all = plt.figure()
fig1 = fig_all.add_subplot(1,2,1)
fig2 = fig_all.add_subplot(1,2,2)
fig_all.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But it didn't work. How can I combined several grouped bar charts into a single figure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I tried something. Here's a rough result. Only thing I changed is that rather using axes, I am just using subplot as I learned over time. So with `fig` and `axes` as output, there must be a way too. But this is all I've ever used. I've not added the legend and title yet, but I guess you can try it on your own too.

Here's the code with just small change:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3']
yesterday_test1_mean = [20, 12, 23]
yesterday_test2_mean = [21, 14, 25]
today_test1_mean = [18, 10, 12]
today_test2_mean = [13, 13, 9]

x = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.3

plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.bar(x-width/2, yesterday_test1_mean, width)
plt.bar(x+width/2, yesterday_test2_mean, width)    

plt.subplot(122)
plt.bar(x-width/2, today_test1_mean, width)
plt.bar(x+width/2, today_test2_mean, width)

plt.show()
```

And here's your initial result:
[image]

While you see the result and try some stuff on your own, let me try to add the labels and legend to it as well as you've provided in the sample image.

### **Edit: The final output**

So here it is, the exact thing you're looking for:

[image]

Code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

```
labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3']
yesterday_test1_mean = [20, 12, 23]
yesterday_test2_mean = [21, 14, 25]
today_test1_mean = [18, 10, 12]
today_test2_mean = [13, 13, 9]

x = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.3

plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('Yesterday', fontsize=18)
plt.bar(x-width/2, yesterday_test1_mean, width, label='test1', hatch='//', color=np.array((199, 66, 92))/255)
plt.bar(x+width/2, yesterday_test2_mean, width, label='test2', color=np.array((240, 140, 58))/255)
plt.xticks([0,1,2], labels, fontsize=15)


plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('Today', fontsize=18)
plt.bar(x-width/2, today_test1_mean, width, hatch='//', color=np.array((199, 66, 92))/255)
plt.bar(x+width/2, today_test2_mean, width, color=np.array((240, 140, 58))/255)
plt.xticks([0,1,2], labels, fontsize=15)

plt.figlegend(loc='upper right', ncol=1, labelspacing=0.5, fontsize=14, bbox_to_anchor=(1.11, 0.9))
plt.tight_layout(w_pad=6)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was struggling for finding the solution for ages. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: FYI: the legends is not shown :)

Answer (score 1):

There is two method for doing subplots that you might try to combine accidentally: `plt.subplot` and `plt.subplots`.

Here is example how you can use `plt.subplots` to create two bar charts.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3']
yesterday_test1_mean = [20, 12, 23]
yesterday_test2_mean = [21, 14, 25]
today_test1_mean = [18, 10, 12]
today_test2_mean = [13, 13, 9]

x = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.3

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.bar(x-width/2, yesterday_test1_mean, width)
ax1.bar(x+width/2, yesterday_test2_mean, width)

ax2.bar(x-width/2, today_test1_mean, width)
ax2.bar(x+width/2, today_test2_mean, width)

plt.show()
```

There is only little changes on your code. You can add labels with:

```
ax1.set_title('Yesterday')
ax2.set_title('Today')

ax1.set_xticks(x)
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax2.set_xticks(x)
ax2.set_xticklabels(labels)
```